# mysql update a column with data from a set of columns whichever is nonzero

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a table with a number(>10) of columns. Now I need to update a column(rc) that gets updated with contents of other column based on different conditions(4 in total). I am using case to do this but in the case of last one, the condition is that if none of the above 3 work, I need to set the rc column as follows.

I need to check whichever column among five test columns is non zero and set its contents in the rc column.

Please help me how I can do this.

Here is what I'm doing

```
UPDATE <table_name> 
SET CASE
WHEN {condition_1} THEN col_1=true, rc = CONCAT("Reason is", col_2)
WHEN {condition_2} THEN col_1=true, rc = CONCAT("Reason is", col_3)
WHEN {condition_3} THEN col_1=true, rc = CONCAT("Reason is", col_4)
```

**`WHEN {I'm stopped here} THEN col_1=true, rc = CONCAT( " Reason is", {whichever column is non- zero})`**

```
END
```

Please help me with the last condition what should be the statement. Remeber I'm doing all this by passing a query from a C++ program.

Comment: I smell a DB design flaw here.

Comment: let me rephrase: Ugly queries like this are a sign that your schema is not rigthly designed. as I don't know what you're doing I cannot possibly give further advice.

Comment: There are 4 conditions I need to check and in each case I'll set the col_1 to true and rc column to a stmt that says "reason is" the value from the particular column. But in case of 4, the condition is I need to check the contents of 5 columns and set the reason as "reason is" the name of the column which is non-zero among the 5.

Comment: If more than one column is a non-zero, then? What should be the order of checking for a non zero? col1 to col5 in sequence?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have used some other procedure to solve this issue. I am retrieving all the data at once, processing using c++ and then updating the table.

This can be done using some programming languages. Fetch the data using database APIs specific to the language and then process them accordingly. It can then be updated to the database.